# What's the difference between IN and INNER JOIN in my case?

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL database, table events has a composite index with columns closingeventid, timeStart and eventCode. There are more than 21 million rows in table events.

Here is two SQLs, if I run the first one in MySQL command line, the Mem Usage of process mysqld-nt.exe increases gradually with 10 M per second, it goes up around 1.6 G then plummets to around 30 M. Then the command line returns a Out of Memory exception.

But, it's ok if I use the second SQL, with INNER JOIN instead of IN. It seems IN clause doesn't hit any index.

Why? Any idea to monitor MySQL execution process like execution plan of MS SQL?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'cnt' 
FROM events 
WHERE 
     (timeStart < '2010-09-22 14:29:10’) 
 AND (closingeventid IS NULL) 
 AND (eventcode IN (SELECT DISTINCT evtcclosed FROM eventclose))`
```

***VS***

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'cnt' 
FROM events 
inner join 
          (SELECT DISTINCT evtcclosed FROM eventclose) ec 
   ON ec.evtcclosed = events.eventcode 
WHERE (timeStart < '2010-09-22 14:29:10’) AND (closingeventid IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 4):

The MySQL optimizer optimizes an `IN (subquery)` clause very badly. It performs nested query for each row of outer query.

To get the execution plan - just add `EXPLAIN` keyword right before your query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

Comment: I believe you're thinking of Correlated Subqueries, which do perform the query for each row of the outer query. A correlated subquery would include a column comparison from the outer query inside of the subquery. For example: SELECT t1.* FROM t1 WHERE t1.id IN (SELECT t2.id FROM t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zerkms!

I tried EXPLAIN on both SQLs, but it seems both of them hit the right index idxEventClosed (closingeventid, timeStart, eventCode). The explaining looks same exception the bold line below. I still don't have much idea about what caused the out of memory issue.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'cnt' FROM events WHERE (timeStart < '2010-10-29 14:29:10') AND (closingeventid IS NULL) AND (eventcode IN (SELECT D
ISTINCT evtcclosed FROM eventclose));
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type  | possible_keys           | key            | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                        |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | events     | range | idxStart,idxClosedEvent | idxClosedEvent | 17      | NULL | 4335955 | Using where; Using index     |

|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | eventclose | ALL   | NULL                    | NULL           | NULL    | NULL |      10 | Using where; Using temporary |

+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-------------------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) AS 'cnt' FROM events inner join (SELECT DISTINCT evtcclosed FROM eventclose) ec on ec.evtcclosed = events.eventcode whe
re (events.closingeventid is null) and (timeStart < '2010-10-28 14:29:10');

+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys                   | key            | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | events     | range | evtNLoc,idxStart,idxClosedEvent | idxClosedEvent | 17      | NULL | 4330270 | Using where; Using index |
**|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL                            | NULL           | NULL    | NULL |       8 | Using where              |**
|  2 | DERIVED     | eventclose | ALL   | NULL                            | NULL           | NULL    | NULL |      10 | Using temporary          |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` - in this case `IN()` is much less performant solution.

Comment: This should really be an addition to the question - rather than comments disguised as an answer.  You can edit your own question.

Comment: Any one can give me any comment about the two execution plan  above? I cannot understand how IN() is much less performance.